# Is there a typical timeline on which Nikon replaces its DSLRs?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100

I want to buy a Nikon D5100 as my first DSLR camera. It's almost a year since the D5100 was announced and I would like to know if there is something similar to the [mac rumors buyers guide](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/) for DSLRs or Nikons in specific?

Is it likely (considering the months passed after D5100 was introduced) that it gets replaced very soon? (any inside info, maybe?)

Comment: Well, there's http://nikonrumors.com -- did you even try searching?

Comment: @stanrogers hello stan and thank you for your suggestion. As you may notice if you look here, you will not find any information about the D5100 timeline http://nikonrumors.com/category/nikon-d5100/ thank you

Comment: I think the point is not to look for rumors about the D5100, but rumors about the successor. We don't really comment on rumors here at this site.

Comment: Note that speculation on future models is off-topic. See the site FAQ and discussion here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras

Comment: the d90 and d700 threw everything out of whack, along with the Dxx00 series

Answer (score 4):

Two years or so is pretty standard among the consumer range DSLRs for Nikon. I just use the wikipedia page for the D5100 and scroll to the bottom where they have a timeline of Nikon DSLRs. That gives you a great idea of the typical model replacements.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, the exact piece of information is missing there:) Would be cool if we could get a date about the d5100 successor.

Comment: I don't know what you mean it is missing? Take a look at this link - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_D5100

Comment: We can't tell the future, and while camera companies often follow patterns, they also tend to keep information on future plans tightly controlled. (At the very least, why kill sales of current models?)

Comment: Hello @mattdm, thats the exact thing this question asks :) Maybe someone has some inside information. Would be cool, still, thank you!

Comment: @HerrKaleun: If someone had inside information, and they posted that information here, they would not have inside information next time around.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be not to wait, just go ahead and whatever camera fits your needs and your budget. I wanted the replacement for the D300s which was rumored to come out last August. There was no announcement, so in mid-September I bought the D300s. Since then, I have taken thousands of pictures and there is still no sign of its replacement.

Since this is your first DSLR, you will have plenty to learn without worrying about whether its the latest model. Most new models have only modest improvements over their predecessor anyway, so you won't be missing much. Concentrate on developing your photography skills and getting the most out of whatever camera you end up with. Some day (years) in the future, you will start to outgrow it and you'll be in a position to know exactly what features you want on your next camera.

Comment: Right on Jloomis, I think this is the best recommendation overall.

Comment: That's how it works with computers as well.  If you need it now, buy it now, otherwise wait.  Don't worry about rumors too much.